# Need help identifying a relic

Tags: relics

I inherited a relic that says S. Margar. vid, has wax seal and thread intact and above seal a number and date 1949 written.  I have been told this is St. Margaret of Scotland, do you agree and what does the vid mean, thank you, Kevin

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Can you provide a picture or two of the relic and its seal and inscription? That might make it easier to identify. You can edit your question to add the photos. Meanwhile, for more on what this site is all about please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 5):

*Vid* means *widow*. [Reference](http://forallthesaints.info/about.htm). The date 1949 is probably when the relic was last verified and sealed.

St Margaret may well be St Margaret of Scotland. But there are a number of other candidates — Wikipedia lists the following, and there may well be more:

Saint Margaret the Virgin of Antioch (died 304) [unlikely, since *widow* is stated!]
**Saint Margaret of Scotland (c. 1045–1093) [widowed]**
Saint Margaret of England (died 1192) [never married; a nun]
Saint Margaret of Hungary (1242–1271) [never married; a nun]
Saint Margaret of Cortona (1247–1297) [never married]
**Saint Margaret the Barefooted (1325–1395) [widowed]

Saint Rita of Cascia (1381–1457) [widowed]**
Saint Margaret Clitherow (1556–1586) [married but not widowed]
Saint Margaret Ward (died 1588) [no marriage recorded]
Saint Marguerite Marie Alacoque (1647–1690) [never married; a nun]
Saint Teresa Margaret of the Sacred Heart (1747–1770) [never married; a nun]

You don't say what the relic is, but St Margaret of Scotland is certainly the best-known widow of that name. If the seal is identifiable, then there may be records available (for which the date and serial number will be useful).

Comment: Saint Rita is a Margaret? I didn't know that...

Comment: @Wtrmute I had a great-aunt who was known as Rita. She and her sisters were all named after flowers: Daisy, Ivy, Florence and *Marguerite.*

Comment: Other "Margaret" equivalents are Maggie, Peggy, Margarita, Meg, Peg, and several more.